# Why does my PDF ask for a password after being retrieved from Visual SourceSafe?

Tags: pdf, visual-sourcesafe

PREFACE: Yes we're moving away from VSS in the next few months.

One of my web projects contains, as one of its files, a PDF. The PDF on our QA site is being pulled from VSS.

A QA tester recently told me he's being prompted for a password when he tries to open it. VSS says the file I have on disk is different than the one it has, so I updated it, but afterwards it's still being shown as different.

So basically VSS is mangling my PDF and the results are so wobbly that Adobe Acrobat Reader is confused and thinks it has a password.

I've tried adding it as Auto-Detect and as Binary. Same results.

Why does my PDF ask for a password after being retrieved from Visual SourceSafe and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Think about what you just asked. You think VSS understands PDF files well enough to add passwords to them? It's much more likely that VSS is corrupting your PDF files, so that Acrobat Reader thinks there's a password.

Comment: I said it was unlikely but I've now clarified the question.

Comment: Upload your PDF somewhere so that we can examine it. Its internals will reveal the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the [SourceSafe 2005 Update](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8a1a68d8-db11-417c-91ad-02aab484776b&displaylang=en) installed?

Handy list of known issues: http://blogs.msdn.com/richardb/archive/2007/06/06/list-of-bugs-fixed-in-sourcesafe-2005-gdr.aspx

The PDF bug was one of the most commonly requested hotfixes: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925234

> I've tried adding it as Auto-Detect and as Binary. Same results.

To be clear, are you adding a version of the file you know is *not* already corrupted?  Even so, there are plenty of other bug fixes on the list above which can cause random file corruption -- try that first.

Comment: Yes, I can verify that the file is not corrupt before I add it. I'll try the update, thanks. Also, do you have to install this on the server or just on the client end?

Answer (score -2):

You can remove PDF password by this tool:
**Advanced PDF Password Remover 5.0**

***Step 1**: Import PDF files*

Click the "Add File(s)" button, browse your computer to find the PDF files and load them.You can import as many as 200 PDF files into this program for every batch processing.The imported files are listed in the file list window as below.

***Step 2**: Set output folder*

You can customize a folder to save the output files all together. The default folder is My Documents\Advanced PDF Password Removerr. Click "Brows" button to specify a folder on your computer, or you can make a new folder manually in the text box.

***Step 3**: Remove restrictions*

Click "Start" button, and the files are processed one by one.
"SUCCEED" is displayed in the Result column after the removing process is finished.